# Question about the proof of Dummite & Foote's 14.4.22 (Corollary)

Tags: galois-theory

[image]

This corollary is in section 14.4 in Dummit & Foote. And here are some questions:

First, they said that $G_1G_2=G$. I think this is because, $G_1\times G_2=G_1G_2$ as $G_1\triangleleft G_1\times G_2$ and $G_1\cap G_2=\{1\}$. I understand the first one. But I don't understand the second one: $G_1\cap G_2=\{1\}$. In fact, if you read more, they state it as a very trivial fact. Why is that? And the book states $G_1G_2=G$ without extra explanation. Is this a clear statement?

Comment: $G$ being a direct product of $G_1$ and $G_2$ is part of the assumptions of the corollary. So this means $G=G_1G_2$ and $G_1\cap G_2=\{1\}$ are assumptions.

Comment: OH, I forgot that. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given a group $G$ and subgroups $G_1$ and $G_2$, the definition of **$G$ is the direct product of $G_1$ and $G_2$** is:

1. $G_1$ and $G_2$ are normal subgroups
2. $G=G_1G_2$
3. $G_1 \cap G_2 = \{1\}$.

Since the corollary assumes that $G$ is the direct product of $G_1$ and $G_2$ we have these properties by assumption.

Remember that, if $G$ is the direct product of $G_1$ and $G_2$, then $G$ is *isomorphic* to $G_1\times G_2$. But $G$ and $G_1\times G_2$ are technically not *equal* since $G_1\times G_2$ is a subset of $G\times G$. But people often still write $G=G_1\times G_2$ when they are not concerned with this distinction, and only care about isomorphism.